# LINQ Query with dynamic number of boolean ANDs

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am working on a search web page for my site.  The requirements state that users can enter text for any combination of 9+ fields and the search should do an 'AND' match when querying the database.  I could fairly quickly write this as a stored procedure using 'ISNULL' but I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish the same thing in LINQ.  I thought I could **query the results of a query**, but I'm getting the error

**"Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method"**

Here's my example

```
var people = db.People

if(null != fname)
{
people= from e in people
   where e.FirstName.Contains(fname)
   select e;
}

if(null != lname)
{
people= from e in people
   where e.LastName.Contains(lname)
   select e;
}

return people;
```

Can I query the resultset of a previous query?  Is there a better approach I'm just not thinking of?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work and seems simpler:

```
people = from e in db.People
    where (lname == null || e.LastName.Contains(lname))
       && (fname == null || e.FirstName.Contains(fname))
    select e;
```

The code you provided doesn't have anything obvious wrong with it, as there is no reason you can't query the results of another query. It looks like `fname` or `lname` are being defined in some way that the SQL generator doesn't understand.

Comment: +1, Good solution, and it works in Linq-to-Sql. Just FYI, I have had problems with that pattern using LLBLGen before.

Comment: If this is passed to SQL in the same form as above it will run *badly*

Comment: @Craig: If this solved your question, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: gbn: How will this run more badly than any other query? There's no way to run a query like this without a table scan, and that's probably orders of magnitude slower than any other part of the query.

Comment: Since this is being interpreted into SQL, Gabe is right that it doesn't matter. However, I generally go with the approach in the original submission because when dealing with Lists (where it's actually running on the .Net side), it will make a (probably negligible) difference. It also seems cleaner to me to build it up incrementally, especially when you end up having more than just a few conditions.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
var people = db.People;
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fname))
    people = people.Where(p => p.FirstName.Contains(fname));
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lname))
    people = people.Where(p => p.LastName.Contains(lname));
return people;
```

Answer (score 3):

How is your `fname` and `lname` defined?

You should look at `PredicateBuilder` here - especially if you also want `OR` at some time:

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I'll sometimes accomplish the same thing in fewer lines by calling the extension methods directly:

```
var people = from e in db.People select e;

if(null != fname)
{
   people = people.Where(e => e.FirstName.Contains(fname));
}

if(null != lname)
{
    people = people.Where(e => e.LastName.Contains(lname));
}

return people;
```